# Custom message box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Im looking at making a custom message box in JavaScript but am wondering how I go about doing it. I have this code below which shows a Yes, No, Cancel message Box:

```
 msls.showMessageBox("Please choose the appropriate button", {
            title: "This is a message box",

            buttons: msls.MessageBoxButtons.yesNoCancel

        }).then(function(result) {

            if (result === msls.MessageBoxResult.yes) {

                alert("You have selected Morning");

            } else if (result === msls.MessageBoxResult.no) {

                alert("You Have Selected Afternoon");

            } else if (result === msls.MessageBoxResult.cancel) {

                alert("You have closed this message box");

            }

        });
}
```

my goal is to rename the button text but im not sure how to do it, here is an example of what I mean:

- **Yes** to be **Morning**
- **No** to be **Afternoon**
- **cancel** to be **cancel**

I know how to change what each button does, its just the small part of editing the text inside the button to say what i want, thanks for any help

im using Lightswitch HTML and the message box is referenced in jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.css file
[image]

Comment: The title of this question doesn't go with the content.

Comment: Which plugin / script provides that showMessageBox function? Did you look up if there is a documentation?

Comment: im using Lightswitch HTML so let me just find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the text of the buttons if you are using the msls.ShowMessageBox API.  The recommended approach in LightSwitch would be to use a Popup.

[Creating a Popup Screen in LightSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn750854.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

to further add to the above answer, this is how it is done:

create a button on screen, then add this in the execute code:

```
if (screen.Table.Variable == true) {
    screen.showPopup("PopupTest");
    } else {
myapp.commitChanges();
```

from this code you can then add multiple popups with an unknown amount of variables or in my case buttons, each button can be coded to do a certain task.

[image]